# Kotlin Multiplatform on IntelliJ is trying to download native dependencies every time

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Every time I create a new `Kotlin Multiplatform` (Mobile shared Library) project in `IntelliJ` and run `Gradle` sync, `Gradle` tries to download native dependencies. This process is long and unsuccessful. Here are some examples of what `Gradle` is trying to do:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It makes every sync very long (several minutes). How do I make it stop?

I'm using `Gradle` 5.1.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after failed import?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition 2018.3. The log is very long and I don't know how to attach it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @yole, this is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28128) but now there is a workaround. Here is a full implementation of the workaround in `Groovy`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral().content() {
        excludeGroup "Kotlin/Native"
    }
    google().content() {
        excludeGroup "Kotlin/Native"
    }
    jcenter() {
        content {
            excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
        }
    }
    maven { 
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
        content {
            excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
        }
    }
}
```

and in `Kotlin DSL`:

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal().apply {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/soywiz/soywiz")
            content {
                includeGroup("com.soywiz")
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        jcenter() {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
        google().apply {
            content {
                excludeGroup("Kotlin/Native")
            }
        }
    }
```